# HttpUrlConnection setting Range in Android is ignored

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying get a 206 response from my server using Android.

**Here's the code.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://aviddapp.com/10mb.file");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1-2");
                urlConnection.connect();

                System.out.println("Response Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Content-Length: " + urlConnection.getContentLength());
                Map<String, List<String>> map = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                            " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
                }
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                long size = 0;

                while(inputStream.read() != -1 )
                    size++;

                System.out.println("Downloaded Size: " + size);

            }catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
                mue.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Here's the output:

```
I/System.out: Respnse Code: 200
I/System.out: Content-Length: -1
I/System.out: Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
I/System.out: Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
I/System.out: Key : Cache-Control ,Value : [max-age=604800, public]
I/System.out: Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
I/System.out: Key : Date ,Value : [Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:45:22 GMT]
I/System.out: Key : ETag ,Value : ["a00000-53e051f279680-gzip"]
I/System.out: Key : Expires ,Value : [Tue, 11 Oct 2016 07:45:22 GMT]
I/System.out: Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
I/System.out: Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:36:42 GMT]
I/System.out: Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4]
I/System.out: Key : Transfer-Encoding ,Value : [chunked]
I/System.out: Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]
I/System.out: Key : X-Android-Received-Millis ,Value : [1475567127403]
I/System.out: Key : X-Android-Response-Source ,Value : [NETWORK 200]
I/System.out: Key : X-Android-Sent-Millis ,Value : [1475567127183]
I/System.out: Downloaded Size: 10485760
```

**Now I'm doing the same thing is pure java.**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://aviddapp.com/10mb.file");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1-2");
        urlConnection.connect();

        System.out.println("Respnse Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Content-Length: " + urlConnection.getContentLength());
        Map<String, List<String>> map = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                    " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        long size = 0;

        while(inputStream.read() != -1 )
            size++;

        System.out.println("Downloaded Size: " + size);

    }catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Here's the output**

```
Respnse Code: 206
Content-Length: 2
Key : Keep-Alive ,Value : [timeout=5, max=100]
Key : null ,Value : [HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content]
Key : Server ,Value : [Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4]
Key : Content-Range ,Value : [bytes 1-2/10485760]
Key : Connection ,Value : [Keep-Alive]
Key : Last-Modified ,Value : [Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:36:42 GMT]
Key : Date ,Value : [Tue, 04 Oct 2016 07:42:17 GMT]
Key : Accept-Ranges ,Value : [bytes]
Key : Cache-Control ,Value : [max-age=604800, public]
Key : ETag ,Value : ["a00000-53e051f279680"]
Key : Vary ,Value : [Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]
Key : Expires ,Value : [Tue, 11 Oct 2016 07:42:17 GMT]
Key : Content-Length ,Value : [2]
Downloaded Size: 2
```

As you can see I'm getting diffrent response codes in both cases. It seems like Android is not passing `Range` to the server maybe? What's happening here?

*PS: I'm getting a 206 if the file size is 1mb.*

Comment: @EJP Can you take a look at this?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto  can you take a look at this?

Comment: give us headers of both requests as well

Comment: Are you positive that the error is in the client? The server might be sending spurious results. Have you tried any other servers? I tried using Postman, and the server did not return a partial file. http://i.imgur.com/IbBqEll.png (edit: worth noting, I used this same system on a different server, where it worked, so the Postman config works)

Comment: @mklimek Check the java code.

Comment: @binoy-babu check my answer please.

Comment: on which version of android are you running it ?

Comment: I use Range requests with HttpUrlConnection in Android. Works fine for me so should work for you too. Something's wrong with your code or your server.

Comment: Hi, I'm just run your code but for download another file (http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db) and I get 206 error as expected, so It looks like the problem is on the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am relatively certain the error is not in the Android code.

It looks like the server might be delivering spurious results.

You can check with a [third party tool (such as Postman)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to determine the headers that web service is delivering.

My results using Postman. As you can see, it is delivering `HTTP 200` (not `206`). It is also not wending a capped `Content-Length`. If the server is yours, perhaps check that it is configured correctly. Also check your code with other servers.

[image: Postman results]

Comment: Perhaps the server is set to only send full files (ignoring the Range header) if Android is detected.

Comment: You could try setting the user agent, if that is the case - `System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");`

Comment: I changed the server.

Comment: What caused the problem exactly? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: I'm guessing the hosting providers are somehow modifying the headers to enforce fair use. Rather aggressive imho.

Comment: It should be in the best interest of the host to allow range headers fully. It reduces their bandwidth usage. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It would be in their best interests to pay attention to support tickets too. I'm guessing they're not very smart. I'm gonna leave a scathing review somewhere. That should teach them something.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty kind sir.

Comment: No problem sir.

Answer (score 5):

Hi Can u try this piece of code, it seems i am getting `HTTP 206` here.

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://aviddapp.com/10mb.file");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");

                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1-2");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    System.out.println("Response Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    System.out.println("Content-Length: " + urlConnection.getContentLength());
                    Map<String, List<String>> map = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                                " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    long size = 0;

                    while (inputStream.read() != -1)
                        size++;

                    System.out.println("Downloaded Size: " + size);

                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

You just have to add this in async task.

Check this result commenting on/off this line.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is related to `Content-Length` being cleared by android implementation by default. Look at the below snippet from the source code where it says it does gzip compression by default.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/2e317a02b5a8f9b319488ab9311521e8b4f87a0a/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java

> By default, this implementation of `HttpURLConnection`
>   requests that  servers use gzip compression and it automatically
>   decompresses the data for callers of `getInputStream()`. The
>   Content-Encoding and Content-Length   response headers are cleared in
>   this case.

Can you try disabling the default caching using below code to check if that works?

`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");`

**PS:** Sorry for bad formattings. Using the mobile version of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like that:

```
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=1000-");
```